# React Router Link Not Rendering Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, web-deployment

So I'm using this `<Link>` component from react, now the issue is if I write
`<Link to='/pathname'> Text </Link>`
it works perfectly... but if I write
`<Link to={{ pathname:pathname, state: {data:data} }}>Text</Link>`
then it changes the url, but doesn't mount the intended component, neither it keeps the previous one, so I'm left with an empty white page.
Though if I refresh, then it loads all the data I intended to load. Why isn't the desired Component rendering ??

Comment: Try this with $ `<Link to={${pathname:pathname, state: {data:data} }}>Text</Link>` and check pathname and states with console.log()

Comment: can you reproduce this issue on codesandbox or somewhere?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same question

Comment: @JahazielVazquez No, I couldn't. please mention here if you find anything